# ifelse with sumx function in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I am trying to create a DAX measure as below. when the Col1 = B0 or Col1 = B1 I would like to sum otherwise i would like to multiple with rate and sum. How to get around with this ? many thanks in advance.

```
CALCULATE (
SWITCH( TRUE() , 
        'myDF'[Col1] = "B0" or 'myDF'[Col1] = "B1",
 
       SUMX ('myDF', 'myDF'[Amount]),

       SUMX( 'myDF', 
             'myDF'[Amount]*'myDF'[Rate] )),

        KEEPFILTERS( 'myDF'[Col2] = "Bla" )
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  SWITCH( TRUE() , 
        'myDF'[Col1] = "B0" or 'myDF'[Col1] = "B1",
 
      'myDF'[Amount], 'myDF'[Amount]*'myDF'[Rate] )
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt seem working

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check this.